# Java Maven Project in Eclipse IDE, HTTP requests work when running as a java application in the IDE, but are blocked by cloudflare when it is jarfile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, discord, cloudflare

I have a java application where I send an http request to communicate with the discord api. The http request class is below.

```
package http;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpRequest {
    private HttpURLConnection con;
    private String postData;
    private String charset;

    public HttpRequest(final String requestURL, final String charset, final String requestMethod,
            final Map<String, String> headers, final String postData) throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;
        this.postData = postData;
        final URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        (this.con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()).setConnectTimeout(15000);
        this.con.setReadTimeout(60000);
        this.con.setUseCaches(false);
        this.con.setDoOutput(true);
        this.con.setDoInput(true);
        this.con.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
        if (headers != null && headers.size() > 0) {
            for (final String key : headers.keySet()) {
                final String value = headers.get(key);
                this.con.setRequestProperty(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public HttpRequest(final String requestURL, final String charset, final String requestMethod,
            final Map<String, String> headers) throws IOException {
        this(requestURL, charset, requestMethod, headers, null);
    }

    public HttpRequest(final String requestURL, final String charset, final String requestMethod) throws IOException {
        this(requestURL, charset, requestMethod, null);
    }

    public void addHeader(final String key, final String value) {
        this.con.setRequestProperty(key, value);
    }

    public void setPostData(final String postData) {
        this.postData = postData;
    }

    private byte[] getParamsByte() {
        byte[] result = null;
        try {
            result = this.postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String finish() throws IOException {
        String response = "";
        if (this.postData != null) {
            final byte[] postDataBytes = this.getParamsByte();
            this.con.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
        }
        final int status = this.con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("HTTP status code: " + status);
        if (status == 200 || status == 204 || status == 201) {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = this.con.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1) {
                result.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            response = result.toString(this.charset);
            this.con.disconnect();
        } else {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = this.con.getErrorStream().read(buffer)) != -1) {
                result.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            response = result.toString(this.charset);
            this.con.disconnect();
            System.out.println("HTTP Request Error:\n" + response);
        }
        return response;
    }

    public int statusCode() {
        int rc = 0;
        try {
            rc = this.con.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rc;
    }
}
```

I send the http request like this:

```
try {
                final HttpRequest rq = new HttpRequest("https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/"+this.serverID+"/channels", "utf-8", "GET");
                rq.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                rq.addHeader("Authorization", "Bot " + this.token);
                rq.setPostData(null);
                res = rq.finish();
                System.out.println(res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I run the application in eclipse, It works as expected, returning all of the discord channels and status code 200. However, executing the jar file created by running as maven install, I am blocked by cloudflare get 403 forbidden and error code 1010. I am completely confused as to why this is occurring. Please let me know if there is a solution.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your *request* is the same in both situations?

Comment: I haven't changed any of the code. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You should use an http library. But the error is probably caused by a missing user-agent or missing access to the guild.